# Additional space in table cells when using multicolumns

Tags: tables, multicolumn, cell, cellspace

How can I left-align all values in the column `T=10`?

```
\begin{table}
{\def\arraystretch{1.4}\tabcolsep=4px
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Class}                  & \multirow{2}{*}{Animal} & \multirow{2}{*}{Trial} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Values}   \\ \cline{4-5} 
 & & & T=1 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{T=10} \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Class 1} & duck & dog &  $323.72 \pm 24.72$   &  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} $67.23 \pm 1.95 $\\ 
& duck & cat &  $8.95 \pm 2.31$   & $3.77 \pm 1.2$\\

& mice & dog & $79.05 \pm 31.04$ & $43446.90 \pm 05.68$ \\
& mice & cat &  $346.41 \pm 6.52$   & $64.34  \pm 3.38$\\ \hline

\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
```

In the cell with `67.23`, there is an extra space on the left that I would like to remove.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Do you have any reason to not use the `l` specifier for the last column?

Comment: Any news? You receive two answer, it is time to accept one of them (by clicking on the check mark at top left side of the selected answer), which solve your problem on the best way for you.

Answer (score 2):

With `S` columns defined in the `siunitx` package you can align numbers at decimal points (which gives to my taste nicer result):

```
\documentclass[border=3mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \sisetup{separate-uncertainty}
\begin{tabular}{ccc S[table-format=3.2(4)] S[table-format=5.2(3)]}
    \toprule
\multirow{2.4}{*}{Class}  
    & \multirow{2.4}{*}{Animal} 
            & \multirow{2.4}{*}{Trial} 
                    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Values}            \\
    \cmidrule(l){4-5}
    &       &       & {$T=1$}           &  {$T=10$}         \\ 
    \midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{Class 1} 
    & duck  & dog   & 323.72 \pm 24.72  &    67.23 \pm 1.95 \\
    & duck  & cat   &   8.95 \pm  2.31  &     3.77 \pm 1.2  \\
    & mice  & dog   &  79.05 \pm 31.04  & 43446.90 \pm 5.68 \\
    & mice  & cat   & 346.41 \pm  6.52  &    64.34 \pm 3.38 \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This answer is only a slight variation on the answer of Zarko. With the environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you can use `\Block` instead of `multirow` with the avantage that the content of a `\Block` is mathematically centering: you don't have to adjust the number of lines (for instance `\multirow{2.4}`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc S[table-format=3.2(4)] S[table-format=5.2(3)]}
\toprule
\Block{2-1}{Class} & \Block{2-1}{Animal} & \Block{2-1}{Trial} & \Block{1-2}{Values} \\
\cmidrule(l){4-5}
&       &       & {$T=1$}           &  {$T=10$}         \\ 
\midrule
\Block{4-1}{Class 1} 
& duck  & dog   & 323.72 \pm 24.72  &    67.23 \pm 1.95 \\
& duck  & cat   &   8.95 \pm  2.31  &     3.77 \pm 1.2  \\
& mice  & dog   &  79.05 \pm 31.04  & 43446.90 \pm 5.68 \\
& mice  & cat   & 346.41 \pm  6.52  &    64.34 \pm 3.38 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]